# How can I make this XMLHttpRequest for Leaflet more simple? Just vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest, leaflet

Can this be better? More simple? 
My Steps:
Created a Google Doc Sheet -spread sheet
Exported as json
Build this ajax js script to make available to leaflet. js app.
https://jsfiddle.net/lukedohner/by80bvL7/
There maybe a more succinct way.

```
  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log("onload + function");
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      //sucessfull load of json
      alert("Here is the data in a alert window " + xhr.responseText);

      var respText = xhr.responseText;

      xhrText = JSON.parse(respText); // convert it to an object

      console.log(
        "json data: xhrText.length >>>>>>>> " +
        Object.keys(xhrText.mysheet).length
      );
      console.log(
        "Object.keys(xhrText) >>>>>>>> " + Object.keys(xhrText)
      );

      var i = -1;

      for (var mykey in xhrText.mysheet) {
        //In case you want to check to see it there is a null value -property
        if (xhrText.mysheet.hasOwnProperty(mykey)) {
          i++;
          window["card" + i] = mykey + " -> " + xhrText[mykey];
        }
      }
    } else {
      // not sucessfull load of json
      alert("Request failed.  Returned status of " + xhr.status);
    }
    createhooks();
  };
};
var ch = {}; // create a var namespace
createhooks = function() {
  var mysheetlenght = Object.keys(xhrText.mysheet).length;
  for (var j = 0; j < mysheetlenght; j++) {
    //console.log(" xhrText.title >>>>>>>> " + j + " " + xhrText.mysheet[j].title);
    ch["title" + j] = xhrText.mysheet[j].title;
    ch["subtitle" + j] = xhrText.mysheet[j].subtitle;
    ch["copy" + j] = xhrText.mysheet[j].copy;
    ch["imagename" + j] = xhrText.mysheet[j].imagename;

    console.log("title" + j + " is " + ch["title" + j]);
    console.log("subtitle" + j + " is " + ch["subtitle" + j]);
    console.log("copy" + j + " is " + ch["copy" + j]);
    console.log("imagename" + j + " is " + ch["imagename" + j]);
    console.log("~~~~~ " + "~~~~~ ");
    //create vars for addLElement function - Display it is the DOM
    titleindex = "ch.title" + j;
    addElement("Title " + j, ch["title" + j]);

    subtitleindex = ["ch.subtitle" + j];
    addElement("Subtitle " + j, ch["subtitle" + j]);

    copyindex = ["ch.copy" + j];
    addElement("Copy " + j, ch["copy" + j]);

    imagenameindex = ["ch.imagename" + j];
    addElement("Image Name " + j, ch["imagename" + j]);

    addElement("~~~~~ ", "~~~~~");
  }
  ch_callback();
};

function ch_callback() { // Use ch.title1, ch.title1, ch.title1, ch.title1, ch.title1... in your add addElement function or in the Leaflet.js L.control.window method
  console.log("callback " + ch.copy1);
}
```

Now I can use the var like this ch.copy1 in the leaflet L.control.window method. Not shown in fiddle example.

Comment: Please make sure you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the body of your question, so that people can reproduce the behaviour you describe, even in the case external resources are no longer accessible. It looks like your linked JSFiddle is down.

Comment: I added more code to the example. Also replaced the JSFiddle link. Maybe the question is too broad? "How to make this code better, more simple?"

Comment: Indeed it is difficult to say what could be improved when you do not even explain what you are doing and what makes you feel it is not optimal. If it works at least, then move on. Optimization is often opinion-based, and above all highly depends on your exact constraints and requirements, which are not described here.